# Looking for more efficient algorithm in vba to evaluate an exponentially growing combinatorics problem

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, performance

**Small introduction**:

I have a set of elements that need to be combined to get all permutations. Given a few additional rules for those permutations i already wrote a light-weight recursive procedure to generate all those permutations and so far I am okay with the speed of this process.

**The problem:**

The "permutations" are given for a set of elements as follows:
Each number is only allowed once, other than that all possible combinatations are allowed

```
Elements: 1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 3c, 5a, 5b

Bundles of connections:
1a-2a-3a-5a
1a-2a-3a-5b
1a-2a-3b-5a
1a-2a-3b-5b
1a-2a-3c-5a
1a-2a-3c-5b
1a-2b-3a-5a
1a-2b-3a-5b
...
```

For each permutation I want to calculate a score which is defined by all the neighbouring connections inside a single combination. For example:

```
score(1a-3c-15g-4e-2a) = connection(1a-3c) 
                       + connection(3c-15g) 
                       + connection(15g-4e)
                       + connection(4e-2a)
```

All the individual connections are give in form of a table as Worksheet in Excel, with a top and left row holding the single elements. The connecting values are than given in form of a range.

The number of permutations can be approximated by 2*x^(x+1) with x being allowed up to 15.

**As you can imagine, the large number of permutations calls for a very efficient algorithm to be able to compute it in a reasonable time.**
So far I can manage x=8 in 3 minutes and x=9 in under an hour. But x=10 would take an entire day.

**My approach so far:**

My first instinct was to look at each permutation at once, filter out each connection and use the following code-snippet:

```vb
Dim pos1 as Long
Dim pos2 as Long
'k_D : array of all elements (from leftmost column where all connections are stored)
'eg: 1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 3c, 3d, ... 15f, 15g

pos1 = CLng(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(current_first, k_D, 0))'position of first element
pos2 = CLng(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(current_last, k_D, 0))  'position of second element
```

With this I can simply address the needed connection by cell-reference.
This is the fastest I came up so far!

Other approaches included creating some sort of a lookup array with all connections and all the values to reduce it to just one call of MATCH. This was much slower - I assume 2 calls on an array size n is faster than 1 call to an array with size n^2.

Most other changes I made tackled other parts of the code, which never really changed anything. The MATCH function seems to be the real bottleneck in my approach.

I am hoping a new set of eyes could give some new new ideas.

**UPDATE 2020_09_30 - 13:30**
As asked: My implementation on how to get the score of each bundle.

```vb
Function getConsistency(current_buendel As String)
    'This function takes a bundle like "1a-2a-3a" und sums up all given entries. 

    Dim i1, i2, i3 As Integer
    Dim pos1 As Long
    Dim pos2 As Long
    Dim sum, sum_temp As Integer
    Dim current_connection, current_first, current_last As String
    Dim connections As Integer
    connections = 0

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim elem As Variant
    
    sum = 0
    Dim counter
    counter = 0

    connections = UBound(Split(current_bundle, "-"))
    
    Do
        'At first the current_bundle is cut into two pieces
        'eg 1a-2a-3a-4a -> 1a-2a and 2a-3a-4a

        'find first '-'
        i1 = InStr(1, current_bundle, "-", vbTextCompare)
        'find second '-'
        i2 = InStr(i1 + 1, current_bundle, "-", vbTextCompare)
         
        'split current_bundle in two parts
        If i2 > 0 Then
            current_connection = Left(current_bundle, i2 - 1)
            current_bundle = Right(current_bundle, Len(current_bundle) - i1)
        Else
            current_connection = current_bundle
        End If
        
        'work on current connection
        ' Split in two parts
        'eg 1a-2a -> 1a and 2a
        i3 = InStr(1, current_connection, "-", vbTextCompare)
        current_first = Left(current_connection, i3 - 1)
        current_last = Right(current_connection, Len(current_connection) - i3)
        
        'get vertical positions of those projections
        pos1 = CLng(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(current_first, k_D, 0))
        pos2 = CLng(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(current_last, k_D, 0))

        'Handle results
        'This can be done, since the entries in k_ALL2 are lower diagonal
        'shift pos1 and pos2 according to where the matrix is located
        If pos1 < pos2 Then
            sum_temp = k_ALL2(pos2, pos1 + 1)
        Else
            sum_temp = k_ALL2(pos1, pos2 + 1)
        End If
        sum = sum + sum_temp

    Loop While i2 > 0
    
    getConsistency = Array(sum, sum / connections, counter)
End Function
```

The two ranges/arrays k_D and k_ALL2 are presented here:
[image: How the data is given for k_D and k_All2]

Comment: Just a note: `Dim pos1, pos2 as Integer` only declares `pos2` as `Integer` but `pos1` as `Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable. Furthermore the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) does not return an `Integer` but a `Double`, and row counting variables need at least to be `Long` as Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. So I recommend here `Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long` and convert the double from `Match` int `Long` using `cLng( …Match…)`

Comment: Ohh alright. You learn something new everyday. Thanks for the input. I just ran my version against yours and the improvement was around 1%. I guess this lies within the tolerance of how I'm measureing performance. - Question gets updated nevertheless

Comment: @Quallon Sorry, I didn't quite get the idea. Are the connections stored in a 15x15 matrix (just "array" 16x16 with 225 elements)? Or is the size of the matrix much larger, and you only use no more than 15 elements out of many?

Comment: Yes, that is excactl how they are stored. 15x15 fields plus a header column and a left-most column. These two have identical values

Comment: @Quallon Are the item names in the headers sorted? Oh yes, you are using MATCH() with parameter 0, which means they are not sorted. Would it be difficult to re-sort both rows and columns in ascending order? MATCH() with parameter 1 is much faster (using dichotomy)

Comment: The header is in the following form: 1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 3c, 3d, ... 15f, 15g. It is always a number and a letter. I dont know beforehand how many letters each number has, but the average should be up to 3 letters (a, b, c). Is this ordered enough?

Comment: This I was afraid of. The list looks ordered from a human point of view - the numbers are ascending. From the computer's point of view, these are strings, and these strings are not sorted. Sorted in ascending order, this list would look like this - `12a,15f,15g,1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,3a,3b,3c,3d`

Comment: You really haven't defined any of the combinatorial terms in "For each permutation I want to calculate a score which is defined by all the neighbouring connections inside a single combination". It isn't clarified when you given an example which only seems to involve linear complexity. How would you explain your problem to someone who doesn't already know what you mean by those words in this context? A permutation of *what*? A combination of *what*? What is a connection? Are you using "combination" there as a synonym of "permutation"? I really can't grasp what you are asking.

Comment: If your data is stored in the spreadsheet and you are constantly reading from the spreadsheet, you could speed things up by first reading the data into a VBA data structure (perhaps a dictionary if you need to do a lot of lookups)

Comment: @JohnColeman I notice that the word "permutation" is used but the count of permutations doesn't match the usual formula for how many permutations there are.  So the combinatorial terms may not have their usual combinatorial meanings.

Comment: @JohnColeman An example of tose "permutations" has been added to the main question. I am not an expert in the field of combinatorics, but I had the feeling it must have something to do with it. The estimation of 2x^(x+1) of those bundles or permutations was estimated empirically and gives a small overestimate of 7 percent

Comment: In your example in the edit, are there 24x3x2x3x2 = 864 possible "bundles of connections"?

Comment: yes indeed! Would you care elobarte?

Comment: 24 = 4! = number of permutations of `{1, 2, 3, 5}` for each such permutation, there are 3 choices for the letter with 1, 2 choices for 2, 3 for 3 and 2 for 5. Mathematically, this sort of seems like a Cartesian product where you are permuting the order of the indices.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know at least with what I'm working with right now.

Comment: The best speedup would be to create a connection dictionary-of-dictionaries, so that e.g. `connection(4e-2a)` is a simple lookup: `connection("4e")("2a")` (or something similar). It would help if you given a mock table and enough other details so that you have a [mcve].

Comment: Question has been updated to give more information

Comment: Is `connection(1a-3c)` the same as `connection(3c-1a)`?

Comment: Yes, they are. But my recursive function to generate all bundles is not able to efficiently figure out if it's a reverse bundle. I am well aware of this problem but the benefit would be a performance increase by 2, which is nothing compared to the exponential increase for additional elements

Comment: I would not focus on the possible overlap between `connection(1a-3c)` and `connection(3c-1a)`. Now, for this particular task, this may not matter, but if the algorithm will be applied to other data, then such a "simplification" may be wrong. For example, if we will calculate the length of the route between several points, it may turn out that the road from 1a to 3c is several times longer than the road in the opposite direction (no mysticism, in real life this happens often)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest speedup would be obtained by touching the spreadsheet as little as possible. Create a global dictionary which associates strings like `"2c"` to the index in the values, and store those values themselves in a global array. If you are looping over a large number of bundles, the initialization code will only run once:

```
Option Explicit

'module-level variables:

Dim index As Variant
Dim connections As Variant
Dim initialized As Boolean

Sub Initialize()
    initialized = True
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Set index = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    index.CompareMode = 1
    With Range("k_D")
        n = .Cells.Count
        For i = 1 To n
            index.Add .Cells(i).Value, i
        Next i
    End With
    
    connections = Range("K_ALL2").Value
End Sub

Function getConsistency(current_bundle As String) As Variant
    'This function takes a bundle like "1a-2a-3a" und sums up all given entries.
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim sum As Variant, terms As Variant
    
    If Not initialized Then Initialize
    
    terms = Split(current_bundle, "-")
    sum = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(terms) - 1
        r = index(Trim(terms(i)))
        c = index(Trim(terms(i + 1)))
        If r > c Then
            sum = sum + connections(r, c)
        Else
            sum = sum + connections(c, r)
        End If
    Next i
    getConsistency = sum
End Function
```

Comment: The biggest speedup would be to implement one of many known algorithms to solve travelling salesman problem. The main issue is that the question is clearly an XY problem.

Comment: @BrakNicku It isn't clear that this is a TSP problem, despite the similarities. OP never explained  what they actually do with these scores, so I don't know if the goal is to find a bundle that minimizes it. Also, the bundles are not arbitrary permutations of the index set, but are constrained in some ways. For the screenshot -- the number of bundles would be 29160, which is vastly smaller than 15!. It might be the case that it is reducible to the TSP, but I don't think that enough information has been given to be sure.

Comment: Yes, this should work fast. I suggest removing the Trim () functions. In the end, we generate the input string current_bundle ourselves, so there will be no extra spaces there. And an "empty" call to a function that does nothing is, though not very large, but a waste of resources. In addition, I propose to calculate `r` before the start of the cycle, receive only `c` in the cycle, and reassign `r = c` before the `Next i`.

Comment: @JohnSUN I have no idea how the algorithm generates the bundles, so `trim()` was just defensive programming. You could of course tweak the algorithm, but `O(1)` lookup in pure VBA vs. `O(n)` lookup in the spreadsheet itself will dwarf any other time savings.

Comment: _It isn't clear that this is a TSP problem_, _OP never explained_, _so I don't know if the goal_, _but I don't think that enough information has been given to be sure_ Looks like we agree that the question is not clear. Of course making sure that _score_ is calculated in O(1) is an improvement,  but the core still remains O(n!).

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Hopefully i can make use of this appraoch for other bottlenecks as well

Comment: And it is not an optimization problem. Just to clarify